# AngularJS + Plotly - don't want to find my #div

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, plotly

I'm new to AngularJS. I need to connect angular script to plotly. The idea is to get JSON data for X and Y for Plotly. Everything is fine till plotly line. It doesn't find my divs chart0, chart1, chart2... etc. But they are generated by ng-repeat ($index). I get error "No DOM element with id 'chart2' exists on the page". This is my code:

```
app.controller('archive', function($scope, $http) {

var layout = { margin: { l: 40, r: 20, b: 35, t: 20, pad: 4 } }

$http.get("json.php?module=archive").then(function(response) {

    $scope.sensors = response.data;

    angular.forEach($scope.sensors, function(value, key) {            
        var data = [{ x: value.x.split(","), y: value.y.split(","), type: 'scatter', name: value.name }];
        Plotly.newPlot("chart"+(key-1), data, layout, {displaylogo: false, showLink: false, autosize: false});
    });

}, function(response) {
    alert("Error: "+response);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

An [Angular Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) would be a good solution to this problem.  Directives let you attach code to DOM elements created dynamically at runtime.  Directives can also help you build modular and reusable code.  The chart creation sequence would include:

1. Load data from the server, and transform it for Plotly.  Save the transformed chart data to a scope variable.
2. Use the chart data to create instances of the chart directive using `ng-repeat`, passing the individual chart's data to the directive.
3. Initialize the Plotly chart in the directive, where both the data and the element are available.

I built a simplistic working [sample of an Angular Directive for Plotly charts](http://plnkr.co/edit/nG6JtouoArWhbezzlMAo?p=preview) to illustrate the concept.

But you don't need to use my dumb code, you might want to check out [angular-plotly](https://github.com/alonho/angular-plotly) or a similar project that is more complete.

**Load and Transform the Data**

```
  $scope.loadData = function () {
    var rawSensorData = [
      {
        "name": "Chart One",
        "x": "1, 2, 3",
        "y": "2, 4, 6"
      },
      {
        "name": "Chart Two",
        "x": "2, 4, 6, 8",
        "y": "1, 2, 3, 5"
      }
    ];
    $scope.sensorChartData = rawSensorData.map(function (value, key) {
      var data = [{ x: value.x.split(","), y: value.y.split(","), type: 'scatter', name: value.name }];
      return data;
    });
  };
```

**ng-repeat Directive in HTML**

```
<plotly-chart chartdata="sensor" layout="layout" options="options" 
    ng-repeat="sensor in sensorChartData">
</plotly-chart>
```

**Initialize Chart in Directive**

```
testApp.directive("plotlyChart", [
  function () {
    function plotlyChartLink (scope, element, attrs) {
      Plotly.plot(element[0].firstChild, scope.chartdata, scope.layout, scope.options);
    }
    var directive = {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
          chartdata: "=",
          layout: "=",
          options: "="
      },
      template: "<div class='chart'></div>",
      link: plotlyChartLink
    };
    return directive;
  }
]);
```